# MAMP Pro images not refreshing on Mountain Lion

Tags: php, apache, mamp

I use mamp Pro on a daily basis to test out php based sites locally, though I'm a simple designer and writing PhP really isn't my thing.
The problem I've been having since I installed OS X ML is that when testing sites in browsers the images seem to cache once, then never refresh, even after replacing the same image or editing it in PS.

I think it's an image caching issue with MAMP since it happens in all browsers unless I clear out the cache before refreshing the page.
HTML and CSS update perfectly fine.

Needless to say, this is a massive problem since it means instead of a simple page refresh I need to do a whole bunch of stuff for testing.

Anyone had this issue or could offer a solution?

Answer (score 5):

MAMP appears to enable [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html) by default (at least on my MAMP 2.1.0 install) so you should be able to add some appropriate settings in a .htaccess file.

Default to expire immediately:

```
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "now"
```

Or with more granularity (modify the expiries to suit your testing):

```
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "now"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 10 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 10 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 10 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2 minutes"
 ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2 minutes"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 10 minutes"
 ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 5 seconds"
```

If there is an error about invalid directive, you need to enable `mod_expires`.

- In MAMP PRO this is done on the Server => Apache tab .. make sure the `expires_module` module is checked.
- In vanilla MAMP you can edit `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`.  There should be a commented out line similar to:

  # LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so

  ... remove the leading "# " to uncomment.

After enabling `mod_expires` you need to use the MAMP admin interface to Stop/Start servers and the Expires directives should now be available.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the long, detailed reply.
mod_expires is of course enabled (using mamp pro with the htdocs folder in the mamp directory).
I'm not sure how to create an .htaccess file within mamp though, would you be able to tell me how to do that?

Comment: @andy: [dot files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_files) like `.htaccess` are hidden by default in the Finder, so the easiest way to create is using [Terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(OS_X)).  Start a new Terminal session, change to the top level directory for your web documents and create/edit using `nano .htaccess`.  Alternatively, you can add the Expires* directives into your `httpd.conf` (edit `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` and either add directly or as an [Include directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#include)).

Comment: So I added  ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "now"

At the bottom of the httpd.conf file and the problem persists (have to hold cmd +R and spam it to get the change to show up).
I'm sorry, but I have no idea how to use terminal and I don't know much about .htaccess, maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: @andy: did you try clearing your browser cache first (in case the old images were still cached)? One way to check the expire headers are being set: open a image url from your local webserver in safari, right click and select "Inspect Element", then refresh the page.  In the right panel of the web inspector you should see a group called "Response Headers" which should include `Date` and `Expires` values for the image.  If you are not sure if the .htaccess file is being used, try putting in an obvious typo (Apache should complain if it tries to read an invalid .htaccess).

Comment: This is what I see what I check an image url from the localhost
http://i.imgur.com/pHYBA.png
and this is my httpd.conf http://pastebin.com/LRLt3ReN

I think something is wrong since I see no response headers on the image.

Comment: @andy: The apache conf seems as expected; try refreshing the image url when the web inspector is open .. that should show the response headers.

Comment: Safari 6 doesn't seem to allow me to refresh the window while the web inspector is open.
cmd + R just seems to initiate a refresh, then it never goes anywhere and the web inspector looks like this -
http://i.imgur.com/RBzQE.png

Comment: Ok so I finally got the response headers on the WI, no thanks to safari 6.
http://i.imgur.com/1XcLd.png

Answer (score -1):

On mamp my pages wouldn't refresh till i disable the cache. Maybe it will work for your images.
There is a cache, in your MAMP preferences if you use the php version 5.5.3.
The same thing happen to me, I found the solution there: [MAMP time between seeing live changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079089/mamp-time-between-seeing-live-changes)

 

 
In your MAMP Dir go to : /bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini
 
And comment the Opcahe lines:

```
[OPcache]
;zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/opcache.so"
;  opcache.memory_consumption=128
;  opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
;  opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
;  opcache.revalidate_freq=60
;  opcache.fast_shutdown=1
;  opcache.enable_cli=1
```

Comment: nope, it doesnt work