# Why is my PHP file using MAMP not refreshing?

Tags: php, mamp

I have a pretty standard PHP file that I use with MAMP to replicate apache on my local machine.

But for some reason when I make a change to the php file, the changes are not reflected even when I hard refresh in Chrome (multiple times.)

Even simple changes to the HTML are not reflected.

I changed the Document Root, restarted Apache and made sure PHP wasn't running any cache extensions in MAMP.

Comment: Mostly likely your not hitting the correct file with your browser.

Comment: I know it sounds like I am not hitting the right file, but I am. I make a change, refresh, and Chrome reflects that change. But if I make another change, and refresh, nothing happens in Chrome.

It works once and craps out.

Comment: I would take the browser out of the equation and use Terminal to do either a manual HTTP request with telnet or run `php -r 'echo file_get_contents('http://<yourlocalserver>/<yourscriptpath>');'`

Comment: Your not crazy I had a setup on a recent computer that did this. Restarting the server for file changes is the only thing that worked. Still trying to figure why it's happening.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I just ran into this. I found the answer in another thread -- it's the OPcode caching, which you can disable by commenting out some lines in php.ini.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19268769

[image]

Comment: make sure you change the version of the php.ini in the /bin/php/php[VERSION} folder and not /conf/php[VERSION] folder.

Comment: I can't make this work for the 7.0.9 php version, changed both dev and production ini :(

Answer (score -2):

You can also restart apache

`sudo service apache2 restart`

This should also reload your modified scripts.