# Stop caching my pages during local development

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, caching, safari

I've been working on a set of web development projects over the last few months, and have encountered the following problem: no matter what I do, every browser I have caches every page I load, which makes it impossible to know if an edit hasn't worked or if I'm viewing a cached version. I've tried Google Chrome, in Incognito Mode and with the Developer Tools open.  I've tried Mozilla Firefox, gone into about:config and disabled every single kind of caching I could find.  I've tried Safari Private Mode. I've cleared my cache several times on each browser.  I've tried adding headers that should prevent caching.  I've tried appending a random number to the URL so the URL changes every time I open the page; I am still getting cached versions of the page somehow.  Does anyone have any tips, in any of these browsers, to make the constant caching of pages stop? I'm running Mac OS X Mavericks, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using MAMP?

This happened to me, and had to do with a newer version of MAMP.
In your MAMP Dir go to : /bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini
And comment the Opcahe lines:

```
[OPcache]
;zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/opcache.so"
;  opcache.memory_consumption=128
;  opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
;  opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
;  opcache.revalidate_freq=60
;  opcache.fast_shutdown=1
;  opcache.enable_cli=1
```

Original answer by @coding-addicted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199165/php-edits-not-displayed-immediately-when-using-mamp-in-osx-and-php-version-5-5-3)