# How do I update the source code with mamp?

Tags: php, mamp

I just downloaded mamp 3 with php 5.5.10. I created a new file with just php and put in the htdocs folder and it displayed correctly in chrome. But then I added some html and it displayed nothing. I checked the source code and it had one blank line. How do I fix it so that it displays the HTML and PHP? Also, why does this happen?

initial php was

```
<?php echo 'hi';?>
```

then i changed it to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>food</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
echo 'hi';
?>
<form method="post" <?php echo "action=\"$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']\"";?>>
<input type="text" name="food" placeholder="enter a food name">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post your code. we have no idea what you put in the file.

Comment: first it was just <?php echo 'hi';?>

Comment: then it was <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>food</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo 'hi';
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']";?>">
<input type="text" value="food">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You should update your question with the html, not post it as a comment. click the edit button in the bottom left of your question. Paste code. You can highlight the code and click the `{}` button in the editor to format it as code.

Comment: You need step-by-step debugging assistance which is not appropriate in a Q&A repository. Please locate a message board or chat room or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is goofy:

```
<form method="post" <?php echo "action=\"$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']\"";?>>
```

change it to:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

Chances are you just don't have error reporting turned on. Otherwise you'd see this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/index.php on line 10
```

Turn on error reporting:

Open up /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/{your PHP version}/conf/php.ini.

Find display_errors = Off (around line 277) and change it to display_errors = On.

Restart MAMP.

borrowed error reporting instructions form here:
http://gilbert.pellegrom.me/enable-php-error-reporting-in-mamp/

Answer (score 0):

[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079089/mamp-time-between-seeing-live-changes/19268769#19268769)

Answer - obviously change php version to suit.

> The solution is uncommenting lines in the php.ini file which can be found in /MAMP/Directory/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini

Comment out Opcache:

```
[OPcache]
;zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/opcache.so"
;  opcache.memory_consumption=128
;  opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
;  opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
;  opcache.revalidate_freq=60
;  opcache.fast_shutdown=1
;  opcache.enable_cli=1
```

Documentation (yes it started in 5.5):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php