# MAMP - Pages on localhost aren't refreshing (PHP 7.3.8)

Tags: caching, localhost, mamp, php-7, browser-cache

I'm halfway though this project I've set up in MAMP and all of the sudden it doesn't show any of the changes I make anymore.

The site is showing but it doesn't show the latest changes (even big HTML changes).
It seems like a caching issue. I've deleted the cache in my browser, did hard refreshes, changed the MAMP preferences to an older version of PHP (7.2.21) and commented [OPcache] out in the php.ini file (as suggested on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079089/mamp-time-between-seeing-live-changes/19268769#19268769)).

This problem seems to occur more often with php5. But since my version of MAMP is only running php 7 I can't find a solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As silly as it sounds, the only one way I found to get away from that issue was by adding any text on the view that I wanted to be refreshed and re-loading the page. MAMP was detecting that update on the view and loaded the correct version instead of the cached version. The OPcache fix did not work for me either.